# C++ Passing unknown function as an agument

Tags: c++

My problem is following, I have a function which takes one function as a parameter. The problem is that in some cases the passed function fEval() needs to be called with two parameters instead of one as fEval(somevalue1,somevalue2)

```
Func(double (*fEval)(double F1),double min, double max,...)
{
    double value1 = fEval(10);

    // do something here

    double value2 = fEval(20,30);
}
```

So what would be the correct way to implement Func function ?
I know I can't do it either

```
Func(double (*fEval)(double F1),double min, double max,...)
```

or

```
Func(double (*fEval)(double F1,double F2),double min, double max,...)
```

Thanks !

Okay let me rephrase the problem. I need to create a function which could take a one unknown function as a first parameter, two different values and an argument list.
Something like

```
double Function(RandomFunction, val1, val2, ...);
```

The random function will be either:

```
double Func1(double x)
{
    m_x = x;
    //Calling function
    // Set other things
}
double Func2(double x,double y)
{
    m_y = y;
    m_x = x;
    //Calling function
    // Set other things
}
```

I'll try that functor way but I'm not sure is it right way to do this ? Doesn't it require me to overload () inside of the possible functions what could be called ?

Comment: Sounds like an instance of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. You may get better help if you describe your problem instead of your attempted solution.

Comment: "The random function will be either..." Why do you need it to be either? How are you going to determine which it is, when you receive it?

Comment: Karl that's actually my problem that I don't know how could I detect it. My function is a some kind of variation of the bisection and sometimes it'll get a function what takes 1 parameter and sometimes 2 parametes.

Comment: @Mare : Are you using a C++11 compiler? If so, it's trivial to detect the arity of a function.

Comment: I'm not, I'm using g++ / gcc 4.4.3 at the moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably should require a functor that has `operator()` overloaded to take one or two arguments:

```
struct Functor {
    double operator()(double d) {
        ....
    }

    double operator()(double d1, double d2) {
        .... 
    }
};

void Func(Functor f, double min, double max, ...) {
    double value1 = f(10);

    // do something here

    double value2 = f(20, 30);
}
```

Other than that (besides passing around variadic functions, which wouldn't be good because it couldn't know whether it was being called with one or two arguments) I don't think there is another good way to have a function that can take both 1 or 2 arguments.

And as ildjarn mentioned in the comments, you could also make it a template so it can take any kind of functor:

```
template<typename Functor_t>
void Func(Functor_t f, double min, double max, ...) {
    // same as above
}
```

Comment: +1, but `Func` should be a function template so that it can take any functor rather than restricting itself to `Functor`. After all, it originally took a function pointer specifically so that the caller could specify the behavior...

Comment: I'm sure this method could be correct but anyway I did it the easiest way and wrote overloaded function. I guess I should have done this at the first place.

Thanks anyway guys!

Comment: @Mare you can't pass that to another function though.

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned above I ended up writing overloaded functions as I should have done at the first place and well now it works as I wanted.